# Libgdx: Texture cannot be cast when AssetManager.Update() returns true

Tags: java, libgdx

I am learning how to use libgdx and i dont found an awsnser to this either for here or docs.
My problem is very clear in the title. When i try to get a texture loaded 5 seconds before ( this is because i am using a Gdx timer, only for testing) the aplication crashes and gives this

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture cannot be cast to com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image
at com.hoticecream.mad.Background.setStaticBackground(Background.java:33)
at com.hoticecream.mad.Playgorund$1.run(Playgorund.java:102)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.executeRunnables(LwjglApplication.java:257)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:208)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

i will post the whole class because is short

```
 class Background {

    private  Image background;
    private final String backgroundName;
    private  AssetManager manager;

    Background(AssetManager manager){

        this.manager = manager;

        background = new Image();

        backgroundName = "background1.png";
        manager.load(backgroundName, Texture.class);
        manager.finishLoadingAsset(backgroundName);



    }

    public void setStaticBackground(Stage stage){


        //here is where error happends, affter manager.update() returning true
        if(manager.update()){
            background = manager.get(backgroundName);

        }else {
            Gdx.app.log("Manager","not loaded");
        }

        background.setHeight(stage.getHeight());
        background.setWidth(stage.getWidth());

        stage.addActor(background);
    }

    public void dispose(){

        manager.unload(backgroundName);

    }

}
```

slide note: the asset manager is passed by argument from inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the object (it's texture, because of the set loader type - `manager.load(backgroundName, Texture.class);`) you are getting from the manager is not castable to `Image` type.

Try to create an Image object from the texture:

```
...
if(manager.update()){
    background = new Image((Texture) manager.get(backgroundName));
...
```